# how to include security remider answer in MVC 2.0 membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, registration, membership-provider

I have created a new web application project for MVC 2.0
and the folders and files were automatically added including the register page.

The secret question and answer fields/textboxes are missing and although i can add them to the registration page i'm unsure about how to SUBMIT them for validation in the regisration process.

What is the correct method of including this information during the registration procedure?

IE.
The NEW registrant MUST provide both question and answer in order to create a new profile.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this question automatically when using the editorvia the built in intellisense feature which shows all the available overides that are possible on the revalavent function call.

```
Dim createStatus As MembershipCreateStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(Model.UserName, Model.Email, Model.Password, Model.SecretQuestion, Model.Answer)
```